# Modifying Variables with the Inner Class (Java)

Tags: java, swing, class, variables, calculator

So currently I'm self-teaching Java, and I want to write a simple calculator with little buttons and a text field using Swing. While I managed to actually create a text field with a variable of text filling it, I can't make a button change the text in the field. I keep receiving an error about the inner class being unable to change an outer variable. What would be my best way of accomplishing my goal, and why?

Thanks in Advance, Code below:

Check out where the action for my first button (addButton) is, that's where I was testing the ability to change the text-field.

```
/**
 * Created by Ray on 7/19/2015.
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class main extends JFrame {
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double z = 0;

    public main() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(null);

        JPanel text = new JPanel();
        text.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        text.setBounds(100, 10, 200, 25);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        area.setBounds(100, 10, 200, 25);
        pane.getViewport().add(area);
        text.add(pane);
        String contents = "Test";
        area.setText(contents);
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.setToolTipText("Addition operation.");
        addButton.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                contents = "Pressed";
            }
        });
        JButton subButton = new JButton("Sub");
        subButton.setToolTipText("Subtraction operation.");
        subButton.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        subButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JButton mulButton = new JButton("Mul");
        mulButton.setToolTipText("Multiplication operation.");
        mulButton.setBounds(10, 70, 80, 25);
        mulButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JButton divButton = new JButton("Div");
        divButton.setToolTipText("Division operation.");
        divButton.setBounds(10, 100, 80, 25);
        divButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        add(text);
        add(addButton);
        add(subButton);
        add(mulButton);
        add(divButton);

        setTitle("Simple example");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                main ex = new main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just the variable `contents` is local to the `initUI` method, so you just need to declare it as `final` before using it.\

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Have you tried using `area.append("some new text");`?

Comment: @nIcEcOw `final` will mean that the OP is unable to assign a new value to the variable...

Comment: `contents = "Pressed";` -> `area.setText("Pressed");`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorld extends JFrame {
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
double z = 0;
public HelloWorld() {
    initUI();
}


private void initUI() {

    setLayout(null);

    JPanel text = new JPanel();
    text.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    text.setBounds(100, 10, 200, 25);

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

    area.setLineWrap(true);
    area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    area.setBounds(100, 10, 200, 25);
    pane.getViewport().add(area);
    text.add(pane);
    String contents1="Text";
    area.setText(contents1);
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.setToolTipText("Addition operation.");
    addButton.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           final String contents = "Pressed";
        }
    });
    JButton subButton = new JButton("Sub");
    subButton.setToolTipText("Subtraction operation.");
    subButton.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
    subButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    JButton mulButton = new JButton("Mul");
    mulButton.setToolTipText("Multiplication operation.");
    mulButton.setBounds(10, 70, 80, 25);
    mulButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    JButton divButton = new JButton("Div");
    divButton.setToolTipText("Division operation.");
    divButton.setBounds(10, 100, 80, 25);
    divButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    add(text);
    add(addButton);
    add(subButton);
    add(mulButton);
    add(divButton);

    setTitle("Simple example");
    setSize(500, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HelloWorld ex = new HelloWorld();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

You just need to declare two variables, as we can use only final variables in Method local inner class.Or declare one final variable and use the same name for both Text and Button,which you don't want.
So if you define a normal String outside, you can use it for Text Field normally, but you cant in the method local inner class.
If you define a final variable outside just add it in the method local inner class but don't try to change it again as it is Final.

Answer (score 0):

If you delcare the variable `String contents` as a member of the class, you will not face this problem. In the code just refer to it as `contents` to not override it, so remove any `String contents = ...` declarations from your `initGui()` method.

```
public class main extends JFrame {
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
double z = 0;
String contents = "Test";

public main....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read up on the difference between instance and a class (static) variables.

`contents` is an instance variable of `main`, which means that you can only reference it within the context of `main`. When creating a new `ActionListener`, you are creating a new `Anonymous` instance of `ActionListener`, and attempting to access `contents` from within the instance of the newly created `ActionListener` and not `main`.

You can fix your problem by accessing the `JButton` directly from the `ActionEvent`:

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Component comp = (Component) event.getSource();
        if (comp instanceof JButton) {
            ((JButton)comp).setText("Pressed");
        }       
    }
});
```